# Bootstrap 4 Modal Varying Content not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm having a little problem where I can't get a modal to read data from a HTML table and input it into a Bootstrap 4 Modal. I've tried multiple ways as seen in the code snippets below.

This is just me learning as I need to be able to do it with ASP.Net and have a table filled from a database passing data into a Modal but first need to get a basic Modal working. Can someone please help figure out why this isn't working.

**HTML:**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PlayTest";
}

@model ViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
        <br />
        <br />

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="name">John</td>
                    <td class="age">45</td>
                    <td>Male</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-name="John">View</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="name">Samantha</td>
                    <td class="age">32</td>
                    <td>Female</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Name</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="ageMessage">Age</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
            var _name = button.data('name');

            var row = button.parents('tr');
            //var name = row.find('.name').text();
            var age = row.find('.age').text();

            $(this).find('.modal-title').val(_name);
            //$(this).find('.modal-title').val(name);
            $(this).find('.ageMessage').val('Your age is: ' + age + '!');
        })
    })
</script>
```

It still opens a Modal just nothing is shown apart from the hardcoded "Name" and "Age" not the values from the table which I would expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your JavaScript uses `myModel` as the ID, but your modal has the ID of `myModal`.

Your JQuery function will not be called as the event listener is not listening to your modal.

Instead of `$('#myModel')` use this -> `$('#myModal')`?

Comment: Oops my mistake @odgers.chris, I have edited it for future answers. But that change still didnt solve the problem for some reason.